# Cron job not working when cron file is located outside public_html directory

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I am trying to add a php cron job to my website which is hosted on a remote server. The path of the cron job file is "/home/userid/domains/mywebsite.com/scripts/cron1.php". I have tried the following commands and none of them seem to execute the cron file:

/usr/bin/php /home/userid/domains/mywebsite.com/scripts/cron1.php

cd /home/userid/domains/mywebsite.com/scripts && /usr/bin/php cron1.php

My hosting account does not show any errors for the cron results.

However, if I move the cron file inside the public_html directory and add a cron job with the command "curl [https://mywebsite.com/cron1.php"](https://mywebsite.com/cron1.php%22), it works as expected. But I want the cron file outside the public_html directory and so I know I cannot use a curl command.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or how I can get the cron job to work when the cron file is outside the public_html directory.

Thank You,
Clement

Edit:

My directory tree is:

user
|- domains (755)
...|- mywebsite.com (755)
......|- data (755)
.........|- cronresults.php (644)
......|- scripts (755)
.........|- cron1.php (644)

Edit:

### cron1.php

```
<?php
$path = dirname(__DIR__) . "/data/cronresults.txt";
file_put_contents($path, "random text\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: Can you have your php file dump a log so you can see 1) if it's running, 2) if it's having a problem running? Do you have shell access to the server where you can test running the commands?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do in the cron file (just for testing at least. I will chsnge its code once I find out that everything works fine). Currently, its contents are:

<?php

    $path = dirname(__DIR__) . "/data/cronresults.txt";
    file_put_contents($path, "random text\n", FILE_APPEND);

?>

Sorry, I do not know what shell access means. How can I check this?

Comment: Shell access would mean logging into the server through, presumably, SSH, where you can execute commands via console. It's highly likely that your cron job is running, so the question's surround whether or not your command are correct or if there is a problem with the PHP script itself. For instance, you might be trying to write a file to a path that does not exist, but your PHP script isn't outputting or logging the error so you'd have no way of knowing. Permissions /could/ be a factor as well.

Comment: I do not have SSH. But I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the PHP script because like I mentioned, if I move the cron file inside the public_html directory, it works fine if I run it via a browser or a curl command. Its only when I move it outside the public_html directory that it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, but that's not the same thing. When you run PHP via curl, the script is running as the worker process for the web server, but when you run it via `/usr/bin/php` (assuming that's the correct path), it's going to run as the worker id for cron. This difference in both user as well as the location has implicit permission differences that could be the source of your problem that could also be a problem with how you are writing your PHP. For isntance, you may need to create that subfolder before you can write the file.

Comment: OK, but if you don't know what user CRON is running as, then 755 is going to be a problem. If its running as root, which in many environments is the case, then it's fine, but most likely it's not. You could try changing the permissions to 775 and 664, respectively, and hope that the worker running cron is in the same group as the owner.

Comment: I tried setting the permissions of the "data" and the "scripts" directories to 775 and the "cron1.php" and "cronresults.php" files to 770. It still doesn't work if I use the command /usr/bin/php /home/user/domains/mywebsite.com/scripts/cron1.php 
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use the lynx command (but you must have lynx installed, say yum install lynx )

1 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx  http://mywebsite.com/cron1.php -dump

If you want to use PHP instead , you may try to change

```
<?php
$path = dirname(__DIR__) . "/data/cronresults.txt";
file_put_contents($path, "random text\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

to absolute path (such as the following, but adjust it according to your real path)

```
<?php
$path =  "/var/www/websitename/data/cronresults.txt";
file_put_contents($path, "random text\n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work with just php. I know this is not impossible because I have read other articles where people have done this. I just don't get why it wont work for me. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Yes by using php is ok (I've done it many times). But can you post your cron1.php so that we can check what is the problem when it is run in cron ?

Comment: <?php  
$path = dirname(<underscore><underscore>DIR<underscore><underscore>) . "/data/cronresults.txt";  
file_put_contents($path, "random text\n", FILE_APPEND);  
?>

Comment: Change the php to use absolute path and try again (see my revised answer)

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day (and let's look forward to a better 2021)